# Asymptotic equation for $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\ln(k)^m}{k}$ for $m=1,2,3,4; n\gg0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, asymptotics

Is there a known asymptotic equation for
$$ S(m)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\ln(k)^m}{k} $$

where in particular $m=1,2,3,4$ and it is assumed that $n\gg0$. When looking at the interpolations of 2nd order polynomials, it shows that for $k \in [1,n=819]$

$$
S(1)=-3*10^{-5}n^2+0.0422n+5.8118
$$

$$
S(2)=-1*10^{-4}n^2+0.1964n+12.024
$$

$$
S(3)=-4*10^{-4}n^2+0.9333n+19.718
$$

The logarithmic interpolations are less accurate for something like $a\ln(n)+b$ for some constant $a,b$.

Comment: If $m \ge 0$ is fixed, then by an easy generalization of the proof of the integral test for convergence, you should get $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\ln(k)^m}{k} \sim \frac{\ln(k)^{m+1}}{m+1}$ as $n\to \infty$.  Not sure if that's what you're looking for, especially given that the notation $S(m)$ concentrates on the dependency on $m$.

Comment: It does look like the Euler Maclaurin formula works here

Comment: @BaklavaGain Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

M. I. Israilov [showed](https://www.mathnet.ru/links/bd732d62c626a7cd9784f7beb8bd33ca/tm2377.pdf) that for any $m\ge 0$, $n\ge 2$ and $N\ge 1$,
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{\ln ^m k}}{k}}  = \frac{{\ln ^{m + 1} n}}{{m + 1}} + \frac{{\ln ^m n}}{{2n}} + \gamma _m & + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{N - 1} {\frac{{B_{2k} }}{{(2k)!}}\left[ {\frac{{{\rm d}^{2k - 1} }}{{{\rm d}x^{2k - 1} }}\frac{{\ln ^m x}}{x}} \right]_{x = n} } \\ & + \theta _N (m,n)\frac{{B_{2N} }}{{(2N)!}}\left[ {\frac{{{\rm d}^{2N - 1} }}{{{\rm d}x^{2N - 1} }}\frac{{\ln ^m x}}{x}} \right]_{x = n} 
\end{align*}
with a suitable $0<\theta _N (m,n)<1$. Here, the $\gamma_m$ are the [Stieltjes constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants) and the $B_k$ denote the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_numbers).